# Fortify Cross Site Scripting : DOM - jQuery Fix

Tags: jquery, xss, fortify

i'm trying to fix some issues pointed by Fortify but i'm pretty lost all the way,

if some of you could give me some light, i'd appreciate

I have this snippet of code:

```
} else if($("#id-type").val() == 'D') {
24  $("#column"+$("#id-column").val()).attr("src", "/app/includes/images/down.gif");
25  $("#column"+$("#id-column").val()).attr("width", "10");
26  $(column).ready($("#id-column").val().attr("height", "5"));
```

And Fortify's pointing XSS at line 25, the only idea who came up in my mind is to find #colum or #id-column and try to validate them?

or it could be a false-positive?

Best regards!

Comment: The error comes from line 24.

Answer (score 0):

There as special characters in selectors which need escaping. Your values might not contain these characters but it's a good habit to escape them anyway.

For selector values, you can pass them through [$.escapeSelector](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/) to escape them.

Or as you're looking for an id, you don't need jQuery. You can use `document.getElementById` instead.